# Update Label with Duration of Animation remaining (BEST PRACTICE)?

Tags: ios, animation, synchronization, nstimer

I have animation in my code. as below

```
if (progressanimation != nil) {
    [progressLayer removeAnimationForKey:@"strokeEnd"];
}

progressanimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];

progressanimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
progressanimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

progressanimation.duration = 10.0;
progressanimation.delegate = self;

progressanimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
progressanimation.additive = YES;

progressanimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

[progressLayer addAnimation:progressanimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

This progress animation will complete in 10 seconds. I want to display count down on one label. But If I use Timer, it starts little slower than animation.

This is how I tried Timer, where in method countDown, I am changing label's seconds.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

I read about CADisplayLink but which is quicker, as works on fps.

**What is best and ideal way to change label text along with Animation's duration?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CADisplayLink**

It works on frame per seconds. 60 frames are changes in 1 second. So it means this will call a method 60 times in a second.

By this, you can reduce time so it would be called once a second, 1/60.0;

```
.h

@property (nonatomic, retain) CADisplayLink *displayLink;


.m

 //In ViewDidLoad (For UIViewController) or layoutSubviews (for UIView)

    _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(countDown)];
    _displayLink.frameInterval = 60; //This will force method to be called as 60 frames are passed, means per second.

    [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

-(void) countDown{

     NSLog(@"%d", remainingCounts);

    label_countdown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", remainingCounts];

    // Do Your stuff......
    if (--remainingCounts == 0) {
         [_displayLink removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        _displayLink = nil;
    }
}
```

NOTE: Make sure you **removeFromRunLoop** and nil it.

**Happy Coding :)**